# Will a wireless N mini pci card work with my laptop's built-in wireless G antenna?

Tags: networking, laptop, wireless-networking

If I upgrade the internal wireless G card in my Dell Inspiron B130 laptop to a wireless N card, will I be able to plug in the laptop's built-in wireless G antenna and expect that to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you swap it, it should work. However, do some research on your notebook model first.

There are certain manufacturers that has a BIOS lock to restrict non-authorized cards from working. Most prominently, are the IBM Thinkpad series, but you can hack the BIOS to get around this check.

If there are more antennas needed, not to worry, you can buy an antenna online, and rig it to run the circumference of your notebook. Throughput might drop without an optimally-placed antenna, but it should not be too much of a concern if your base station is nearby.

Answer (score 0):

Like JSidhu said, it should work.  However, there are some wireless N cards that can use multiple antennas.  If your laptop only has one and the new wireless N card wants to use more than one antenna, then you may run into issues.